# h2o.automl in R is not terminating, same code with e.g. randomForest works fine

Tags: r, h2o, automl

I'm using `h2o` in R and RStudio, and `h2o` is working fine. However, when I try to use the `automl()` function, the process starts, RStudio shows progress bars, but after the progress bar reaches 100% no results are returned. The R session and the process just continues running and the R session remains busy. Using the exact same code with `randomForest()` works fine.

Training frame:

```
h2o.init()
peng <- as.h2o(penguins)
```

This doesn't worK:

```
aml <- h2o.automl(y = c("body_mass_g"), training_frame = peng, max_runtime_secs = 30)
```

however, this does:

```
rf <- h2o.randomForest(y = c("body_mass_g"), training_frame = peng, max_runtime_secs = 30)
```

Comment: I don't have experience with `h2o`, but I have observed this behaviour in other packages. Sometimes the progress bar is inaccurate in its reported value. If the session remains in a busy state, it might still be running correctly and needs more time. Try leaving it for a bit longer to see if the process completes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was actually the problem, automl took 5 minutes instead of the expected 30 secs to return the result.